# Get products from a specific year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Want to select a site whose product end date is only 2018.

There are sites which have multiple end dates for products. For Example, For Site A, for Product P1, there will multiple End dates, 2018, 2019, 2020. I want a Site which has a product end date 2018

```
┌──────┬───────┬─────────┐
│ site │product│ EndDate │
├──────┼───────┼─────────┤
│   A  │   P1  │   2018  │
│   A  │   P2  │   2018  │
│   A  │   P1  │   2019  │
│   B  │   P2  │   2018  │
│   B  │   P1  │   2018  │
│   B  │   P2  │   2019  │
│   A  │   P1  │   2018  │
│   C  │   P2  │   2018  │
│   C  │   P1  │   2019  │
│   C  │   P2  │   2020  │
└──────┴───────┴─────────┘
```

According to sample data, the result I need is:

```
2nd row, A  P2  2018
5th row, B  P1  2018
```

The query I wrote gave nothing, I know it's wrong, but in case If you want to take a look:

```
select * from utk1
where EndDate not in (Select * from utk1 where EndDate = '2018') 
AND   EndDate not in (Select * from utk1 where EndDate = '2019')
```

Comment: Does your data look EXACTLY like that? Or is that just a simplified example? So you want all the products with an end date of 2018 is that is?

Comment: It has the same type of columns, I simplified a bit. I want site whose product end date is 2018, but the thing is some sites have multiple end dates for same products like 2019 , 2020. So, how to get only that site whose contract end date is 2018

Comment: maybe i am not understanding but it would just be select * From ukt1 where EndDate  in ('2018') and for multiple years just select * From ukt1 where EndDate  in ('2018', '2019', '20xx')

Comment: Suppose we have Two Sites A & B. Site A has product P1 whose contract EndDate is 2018.  Again for Site A, Product P1 we have a Contract End date 2019. In this senario, the client has already renewed its contract EndDate but In database we have both the dates. And Site B has a Product P1 whose contracts end date is 2018. And it has no other date. So I need only those products from my data whose contracts dates are ending at 2018, so that I can contact them. But there can be Multiple dates for same products. As Clients have renewed there contracts but in database all the dates got registered.

Comment: You should include sample data and desired results in the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff As I'm new here, I was not allowed to include an Image. I can only share a link to an image that will open in a separate tab. Also, this is my first question, so kindly ignore the mistakes if any.

Comment: You shouldn't be posted images for sample data. It should be text, so the ability to not be able to post images (yet) is t an issue. Images of data are more than often unhelpful, as other users can't interact with them, or copy the data to test against. Unless you're expecting the other users to manually type out all your data? You shouldn't ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is okay.  You just need the correct `in` logic:

```
select *
from utk1
where site in (Select site from utk1 where EndDate = '2018')  and
      site not in (Select site from utk1 where EndDate >= '2019');
```

Note:  I don't really believe that you are storing years as strings.  So, you should dispense with the single quotes.  Mixing types is a bad practice.  (If the values really are strings, add the single quotes below.)

If you want this at the product level, then use `exists`:

```
select u.*
from utk1
where not exists (select 1
                  from utk1 u2 
                  where u2.site = u.site and u2.product = u.product and
                        u2.enddate >= 2019
                 ) and
      exists (select 1
              from utk1 u2 
              where u2.site = u.site and u2.product = u.product and
                    u2.enddate = 2018
             ) ;
```

However, I think a better approach is aggregation:

```
select site, product
from utk1
group by site, product
having max(enddate) = 2018;
```

This gets you the `site`/`product` pairs which end in 2018.  Based on the comments, that seems like the most reasonable interpretation of the question.

Comment: @Man . . . Your comment doesn't make sense.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: first 2 solution work well now but when endyear will be 2020 and more then you must add another condition ,that is not good idea

Comment: Yeah, It gave me 5 rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I really appreciate all your help. I was not able to think of any solution. You guys are Awesome.

Comment: Gordon, Man is right. What he meant was that your first two solution are excluding year 2019, but what about subsequent years like 2020? Instead of `where EndDate = '2019'`, you'll need to use `IN('2019', '2020', …)` which is not good, or you will need to use `>` and convert the varchar year to a number. Your last solution will work for the sample data in the question, but not if there are prior years like 2017. You need to add a condition `COUNT(DISTINCT EndDate) = 1` like I did in my answer.

Comment: @RacilHilan . . . (1) It is only reasonable to answer the question that is actually asked.  (2) It seems easy enough to figure out to replace `=` with `>=` if that is an issue in the data.  (3) The third solution actually takes that into account.

Comment: (1) Fully agree, but the question already includes year 2020, so your first two answers didn't account for that and it is trivial to think that more years are there or will be added. (2) Again agree, but if year is `varchar` as it seems to be from the OP's query, then a simple `>=` will not work alone. You need to also convert to number. (3) Yes, I did say that your last solution would work for the sample data, and it is the best approach like you said. It is actually better than my answer if there are no years before 2018 as per the sample data.

Comment: @RacilHilan . . . I missed the 2020 part in the question.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: You still need to convert from `varchar` to number, don't you? Or if you think it is already a number, then remove the quotes from the first answer. By the way, I'm super lazy and would write `> 2018` instead of `>= 2019` :). Yes typing this one extra character `=` will kill me :). Not only typing it, but I would have to read it every time, ahhhh my poor eyes :).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear enough, as you asked for products with EndDate in 2018 and your EndDate column in the sample has multiple 2018 entries, while in the expecting results you only selected two entries without mentioning the criteria that needed to obtain the expected output (or the records pattern). In other word, you're giving the community a puzzle to be solved (or that how I see it).

Anyhow, from the given output, I guess you need to get the sites products that are listed within the year 2018.

So, (If my analytics skills is still in shape), from the given output, the second and 5th rows have been selected because of the their previous rows were in the same year (2018).

IF that's the case, you might need consider `LAG()`  or `LEAD()` functions, they will be useful in your case. 
You can use these functions to add some starting and ending points which will make it easier to filter further.

In the case of your sample, I've used `ROW_NUMBER()` function (for the sake of simplicity). 
The output might vary on the actual data, so you need to check and assure you've got the right output, if you see some incorrect data, then LAG() or LEAD() will be your solution.

Here is the solution with `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [site] ORDER BY [site]) AS RN
FROM YourTable
) 
    SELECT
        [site], 
        product, 
        YEAR(EndDate)
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE 
        YEAR(EndDate) = 2018
    AND RN = 2
    ORDER BY [site]
```

Here is the solution with `LAG()` (To get the previous record)

```
;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT 
    [site], 
    product,
    EndDate AS StartDate, 
    LAG(EndDate) OVER(PARTITION BY [site] ORDER BY [site]) AS EndDate
FROM YourTable
) 
    SELECT
        [site], 
        product, 
        YEAR(EndDate)
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE 
        YEAR(StartDate)  = 2018
    AND YEAR(EndDate)    = 2018
    ORDER BY [site]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following

```
WITH cte (site, product, enddate) 
AS (
    SELECT site, product, MAX(enddate)
    FROM utk1
    GROUP BY site, product
)
SELECT site, product, enddate
FROM cte
WHERE enddate = 2018
```

**EDIT**

A set/[cte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is being created with for each site and product combination its maximum enddate. Afterwards only the ones having enddate 2018 are being considered.
Eg. for site B product P1 the max/highest enddate is 2019, this results in this row not being considered. For site B P2 the max enddate is 2018, so this row is part of the endresult.

Comment: I think it Worked, but Can you please give a little explanation on this. I need to understand the logic behind it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want products that fall in 2018 only and no other years, you need to add a condition of count to be 1:

```
SELECT site, product, MAX(EndDate) AS EndDate
FROM utk1
GROUP BY site, product
HAVING MAX(EndDate) = '2018'
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT EndDate) = 1;
```

Note: from your question, it seems that `EndDate` is a `varchar`. If that's not correct and it is a number, then change `= '2018'` to `= 2018` (remove the quotes). Also this answer assumes that there could be years prior to 2018. If that's not the case, the last line is not required and can be removed.

Comment: Thanks. It's Awesome how there can be multiple Solutions to one single problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this one

```
Select * from (
SELECT site, product, MAX(enddate) as enddate
FROM utk1 
GROUP BY site, product
)a where enddate = '2018'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from utk1
group by site,product
having max(EndDate) ='2018';
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please explain your answer so that other user with similar problem can find it helpful.

Comment: I haven't seen the OP's data, but I doubt that's going to work. `EndDate` isn't in your `GROUP BY`, and you have a `SELECT *`, so you'll get an error about returning columns that aren't within an aggregate function or the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Larnu, with MySQL prior to  5.7.5, although I agree with you that doing so is bad and invalid standard SQL. MySQL has finally addressed the problem and [starting with MySQL 5.7.5, the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled by default](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-changes).

Comment: @RacilHilan this is a SQL Server question. The syntax for T-SQL can be quite different to the SQL used by MySQL.

Comment: @Larnu Oops! Of course, I don't know why I thought the question was for MySQL. All other major databases including SQL Server follow the standard SQL in this regards, so you're absolutely right. Now with MySQL 5.7.5+, all are the same. I will remove my comments to keep the thread clean.

Comment: #Biruk Abebe what should explain in this query